# Local Docker Registry using IP address instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1

Tags: docker

By following the link [local-docker-registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) I am able to create local docker registry. And if I try to use docker pull from the registry then it is working with localhost. However, If i try with the ip address (192.168.1.100) with the docker pull then it got stuck. Is there any way that I can use local docker registry from different node. Like I have started the docker registry in Node_1 and Node_2, Node_3 can use the same registry to download images using repo URL with ip adrres.

```
sudo docker ps | grep 5000 

ac85ef5e1468 registry:2  "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

Docker pull result with localhost

```
$docker pull localhost:5000/<repo path>/<my image name>

2020.3.0-05-e00b8b5: Pulling from <repo path>/<my image name> 
6cf436f81810: Already exists 
...
7a4174f2f781: Already exists
12625989883c: Pull complete 
704db5aa2eb9: Pull complete 
Extracting [===>                 688.1kB/8.76MB 
de0615bc3c45: Download complete
fbaceba9fc67: Download complete
```

With IP Address its not working:

```
$docker pull 192.168.1.100:5000/<repo path>/<my image name>`

Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.1.100:5000/v2/: 
net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
(Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: are you running it on Minikube?

Comment: Additionally, could you post the output of `kubectl get svc` (for the namespace your registry pod runs in) ?

Comment: most probably you forgot exposing it via `minikube expose ...` .

Answer (score 0):

Run this on other node

```
 sudo service docker stop
 vi /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
"insecure-registries" : [ "192.168.1.100:5000" ]
}
//add the entry 
vi /etc/sysconfig/docker
ADD_REGISTRY='--add-registry 192.168.1.100:5000'
// Add this
start the docker service: service start docker
Check the command
docker info
Registry: https://192.168.1.100:5000/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 192.168.1.100:5000
 127.0.0.0/8

This has to perform from all the nodes where you want to make the default registry as private registry.
now run : docker pull <image name>
//it should pull from private registry
```

Comment: Tried both the below options

1. docker -d --insecure-registry 192.168.1.100:5000
and 
2. DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry 192.168.1.100:5000'


Still facing the below error:


Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.1.100:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: Will it work from other node also ? Like registry in 192.168.1.100 and i am trying to pull from 192.168.1.110 ?

Comment: To add an insecure docker registry, add the file /etc/docker/daemon.json with the following content:

{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "hostname.cloudapp.net:5000" ]
}

Comment: # cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{ "insecure-registries":["192.168.1.199:5000"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": { "max-size": "10m",
                "max-file": "5" }
}

Already tried .. and restart docker done .. still facing same issue .. Do i need to create the registry again ?

Comment: Do following check : "docker info"; Check for registry entry from any node; vi 
 to /etc/sysconfig/docker file and add this entry :    ADD_REGISTRY='--add-registry 192.168.1.100:5000'.         restart the docker service. Run the command docker pull <image  name>; it will pull from your registry

Comment: I have also tried editing  /lib/systemd/system/docker.service and docker restart .. but that is also not running 


ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// –insecure-registry ip_address:5000

probably -d option not available any more as described here - https://www.edureka.co/community/12728/how-to-get-remote-access-to-a-private-docker-registry

Comment: By Doing JOSN edit i am able to get output of  curl http://192.168.1.100:5000/v2/_catalog

However, I am still facing the issue ---  net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Any trick ?

Comment: have you solved it?   I have just installed unsecure registry on openSuse and it tags and pushes/pulls from local with no issues.   Not sure why you have added 192.168.1.199 to your daemon.json and pulls from .1.100